# Diffifcult in finding two different iframes with same tag

Tags: html, xml, iframe, xpath, tinymce

I'm trying to find the XPath which is given within iframe with HTML/body tag.

There are two comment boxes with the same tags in my application. I need to find unique id for this.

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="mceFirst" role="presentation">
    <td class="mceIframeContainer mceFirst mceLast">
      <iframe id="summary_ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:"""   allowtransparency="true"         title="Rich Text AreaPress ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press   ALT-0 for help" style="width: 100%; height: 260px; display: block;">
      <html>
        <head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " contenteditable="true"           onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('summary').onLoad.dispatch();" dir="ltr"> 
        </body>
      </html>
      </iframe>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to write XPath for the body id.

Comment: The id of your body dose not seem to be unique. Could you please be more clear about what your XPath should select and what you should filter by?

Comment: can you tell which language you are using? can you tell what you want ot do?